# Error Validatin Wordpress Feed RSS on Mailchimp

Tags: wordpress, rss, w3c-validation

Mailchimp doesn't find my feed rss. 
This is the error using the validating tool

> This feed does not validate.
>
> ```
> line 407, column 19: XML parsing error: <unknown>:407:19: not well-formed (invalid token) [help]
>
>     Page Caching using disk: enhanced (Page is feed)
> ```

This is my feed url: https://www.recipeselected.com/feed/
I don't understand why the pagecache is causing the error.

Problem is in those last lines in the feed :

```
<!-- Performance optimized by W3 Total Cache. Learn more: https://www.w3-edge.com/products/   
Page Caching using disk: enhanced (Page is feed)   
Minified using disk  
Served from: www.recipeselected.com @ 2019-06-17 00:04:12 by W3 Total Cache
-->
```

If i disable page cache and minify the feed is working fine, but I'd like to have them enabled and delete those last lines from the feed.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved removing the Total Cache comment on alla pages.
This is the code to add to the function.php

```
// Disable W3TC footer comment for all users
add_filter( 'w3tc_can_print_comment', '__return_false', 10, 1 );
```